# Вопрос по вложенности python

Tags: python

При введении значения 14, 17 и т.д., получаю ошибку:

`AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'append'`

````
sum = 0
mainList = list()
if count < 10:
  if count < 0:
      print("very small number")
  else:
    for num in range(0, count):
      sum += num
      print(sum)
elif count in range(10, 20):
  for num in range(0, count):
    mainList.append(num)
    mainList = map(str, mainList)
    print("used numbers=", ', '.join(mainList))
else:
    print("very big number")```
````

Comment: а проблема в чем?? вы сами присваиваете `mainlist` объект типа `map`

Comment: Что должен делать ваш код?

Comment: Для заданного значения переменной N необходимо:
- вывести сумму всех целых числа от 0 до N-1, если N<10
- вывести текст "used numbers= 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1", если 10<=N<20
- вывести текст "very big number", если N>=20
Примеры: 
- для N=4 ваша программа должна вывести: 6
- для N=12 ваша программа должна вывести: "used numbers= 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11"
- для N=22 ваша программа должна вывести: "very big number"

Comment: Если хотите обойтись "малой кровью" и минимально вносить правки, достаточно просто изменить третью строку с конца, что бы она имела следующий вид `print("used numbers=", ', '.join(list(mainList)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из условия вашей задачи, думаю, вам подойдет такое решение.

1. В первой части находим сумму всех чисел с помощью функции `sum`. Эта функция принимает на ход список чисел. Создаем этот список с помощью спискового включения.
2. По второму условию используем `f-строки` и функцию `join`. Она принимает список строк. Поэтому в списковом вкючении приводим каждый элемент к строке.
3. В третьем условии просто выводим строку, которую от нас хотят.

```py
if n < 10:
    print(sum(range(n)))
elif 10 <= n < 20:
    print(f'used numbers= {", ".join([str(x) for x in range(n)])}')
else:
    print('very big number')
```